# MS Access conditional formatting for number format display

Tags: number-formatting, conditional-formatting, ms-access-2016

I have a field on my table that can be either a percent or dollar add on ([price_margin] - decimal) with another field that tracks which type it is ([margin_is_dollar_add] - true/false).   I'd like to be able to display that field on a continuous form with the proper number formatting.  As far as I can tell, the conditional format box only allows font color, bold/italic/underline and fill color.  Are there any options for changing the number format based on a condition?

I'm using MS Access 2016.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this when looking for an answer. Have had some success with a textbox and formatting the number:

=IIf(IsNumeric([price_margin),IIf([margin_is_dollar_add],FormatCurrency([price_margin],2,0,-2,-2),FormatPercent([price_margin],1,0,-2,-2)),"")

It is wrapped in another if statement to output blank, if [price_margin] is not a number.

Take care

Comment: Please use formatting to highlight the code